# How to optimize search in list in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to make a SQL query in Mysql to search a string list (for ex: 1,2,3) in a columns (for ex: list_id), which also have string value list (1,2,3).

For more detail, my_table is

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | list_id  |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 29       |
| 2         | 30       |
| 3         | 31       |
| 4         | 4,5,6,7  |
| 5         | 8,9,10,11| 
| 6         | 4,5,8,9  |
| 7         | 1,2,3,6  |
+-----------+----------+
```

The search value is 1,5,8 and I need get the rows have list_id have 1 or 5 or 8 in it's list. Therefore, the result wil be:

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | list_id  |
+-----------+----------+
| 4         | 4,5,6,7  |
| 5         | 8,9,10,11|
| 6         | 4,5,8,9  |
| 7         | 1,2,3,6  |
+-----------+----------+
```

My query string is:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE list_id LIKE '%,1,%'
   OR list_id LIKE '1,%'
   OR list_id LIKE '%,1'
   OR list_id LIKE '%,5,%'
   OR list_id LIKE '5,%'
   OR list_id LIKE '%,5'
   OR list_id LIKE '%,8,%'
   OR list_id LIKE '8,%'
   OR list_id LIKE '%,8'
```

It is match correct what I want. However, the length of query is in proportion to length of list.

Does `REGEXP` is better than `LIKE` in this circumstance?
Does anyone have experience to make another solution better?

Comment: Specify dbms! Different products optimize different things, in different ways...

Comment: And don't store data like that! Comma separated items is a mess, as you may have noticed by now...

Comment: Can you not just put each list_id value in a separate row and make the id column non-unique? You are not using the database correctly as it stands.

Comment: Hi, My project uses Mysql DBMS. In addition, this is from my customer requirement, therefore, I can't change the method to store data.

Comment: That is a horrifying way to store and query data. My condolences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to concatenate commas to your field (or use SET in MySQL or make a better database structure - in which you join on tables in which the related data is stored).

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE CONCAT(',', fieldname, ',') like '%,1,%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regular expressions will work for this. Here is what you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM junk
 WHERE CONCAT(',', list_id, ',') REGEXP CONCAT(',(', REPLACE('1,3,8',',','|'), '),');
```

Results:

```
ID | LIST_ID
5  | 8,9,10,11
6  | 4,5,8,9
7  | 1,2,3,6
```

[**Please see SQL Fiddle demo here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e16c63/2)

We turn the query list `1,3,8` into an alternating group `1|3|8`. You might be able to do this in your application code to avoid using the `REPLACE()` function above.

**UPDATE** Apologies, I mistakenly used `1,3,8` as the query parameter instead of `1,5,8`. But it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to strongly suggest that you change the design of the database (I am assuming you have some control or influence over it).

You should make the `id` column non-unique and then the `list_id` column should contain a single value. You can then search as follows:

```
SELECT id WHERE list_id IN (1,5,8)
```

If it is a big table and there are a lot of list_id values, put an index on the list_id column.

If you need the output in a comma-separated list, then you will need to use an aggregating concatenation function with `GROUP BY` (e.g., `GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL).

If you cannot change the design of the schema, then use one of the other suggestions here.